# Change animation time for properties of a CALayer

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, quartz-graphics

I have a CALayer to animate a change in its image contents. Now, how can I change how long it takes for this animation to take place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's more or less simple. You have an ivar `CALayer *yourLayer`. Then you set the delegate and implement the delegate method `-(id<CAAction>)actionForLayer:forKey:`

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    yourLayer.delegate = self;
    yourLayer.name = @"yourLayer";
}  
- (id <CAAction>)actionForLayer:(CALayer *)layer forKey:(NSString *)event {
    if([layer.name isEqualToString yourLayer.name]) { // Check for right layer

        CABasicAnimation *ani = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:event]; // Default Animation for 'event'
        ani.duration = .5; // Your custom animation duration
        return ani;

    } else return nil; // Default Animation
}
```

Answer (score 20):

You can just call:

```
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:durationSecs]
```

in -layoutSublayers or anywhere else that you modify the layers and expect them to implicitly animate.  This will effect the current implicit transaction and any sub-transactions within this one.

Comment: Where do I get the `CATransaction` object from?

Comment: ```CATransaction``` is a class. ```setAnimationDuration:seconds``` is a class method. In this case it sets the duration for the current transaction.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now.

Answer (score 10):

A different way to do this:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.5f] forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];
//Perform CALayer actions, such as changing the layer contents, position, whatever.
aCALayerObject.contents = [self newCALayerContents];    
[CATransaction commit];
```

That code would animate the change of the CALayer's contents over 2.5 seconds. You can also use this to disable all animations completely. Like this:

```
[CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
```