# Swift - Animating CAGradientLayer via switch statement

Tags: ios, swift, cabasicanimation, cagradientlayer

I have a gradient background that is generated via CAGradientLayer. I also have a switch statement that updates the colors of the gradientLayer depending on other parts of the UI. It works perfectly, however, the "fade" between gradients is very very quick. I didn't even specify this in the swift project. It's just natively fading slowly.

I would like for the duration of the fade to be 0.5 seconds.

Here is my switch statement.

```
    switch newValue{
        case 1..<70:
        gradientLayer.colors = [gradientColor1a, gradientColor1b]
        case 70..<120:
        gradientLayer.colors = [gradientColor2a, gradientColor2b]
        case 120..<190:
        gradientLayer.colors = [gradientColor3a, gradientColor3b]
        case 190..<400:
        gradientLayer.colors = [gradientColor4a, gradientColor4b]
        default:
        gradientLayer.colors = [gradientColor1a, gradientColor1b]
    }
```

The documentation I am reading states you can animate with a toValue / fromValue, however, I do not know how to implement that into my switch statement above. Is it possible to use CABasicAnimation for this?

How can I get these gradients to fade for a 0.5 duration based on the value from my switch? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to set the animation outside of the switch statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing this?

```
CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(0.5)
```

You should be able to put that just above your switch statement.

Take a look at this answer for more insight [Change animation time for properties of a CALayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926351/change-animation-time-for-properties-of-a-calayer)